# LINQ extension method for multiple join with multiple GroupBy requirements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

As an exercise in learning `EF`, I have the following 4 tables. `Person 1toM`, with `Orders M2M`, with `Products via OrderProducts` (*Gender* is an `Enum`):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public IList<OrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public IList<OrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to generate the following with LINQ extension methods:

> A list of products and total `[=Sum(OrderProducts.Qty * Product.Price)]` spent, grouped by product name then grouped by gender.

The result would look something like this:

```
Female  
    Ball      $655.60
    Bat     $1,925.40
    Glasses   $518.31
    Etc...
Male
    Ball    $1,892.30
    Bat     $3,947.07
    Glasses $1,315.71
    Etc...
```

I'm committing myself to **LINQ** extension methods and hope that I can also develop some best practice here. I can't work out how to now group by `ProductName` and aggregate the `Qty * Price` into a total by product:

```
var prodsalesbygender = context.Orders
    .GroupBy(o => new 
    {
            Gender = o.Person.Gender
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ProductName = g.Select(o => o.OrderProducts.Select(op => op.Product.Name)),
        Qty = g.Select(o => o.OrderProducts.Select(op => op.Qty)),
        Price = g.Select(o => o.OrderProducts.Select(op => op.Product.Price))
    }
);
```

I've tried adding `.GroupBy(g => g.ProductName)` to the end but get the error "*The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider.*".

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is an interesting question, but I think you should edit it to be shorter.  Could you cut down substantially on the code blocks in order to just have a minimum viable amount of code to reproduce & represent your problem?  That way more people will read the question and you will get an answer faster.  Also, what have you tried, to no avail?  Mentioning what hasn't worked, briefly, would also improve the question.  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks Max - I've removed some irrelevant properties and accepted your suggestions. Just learning here.

Comment: No worries!  Thanks for cleaning up the question.  I'm no LINQ expert, but the shorter and more readable your question is, the more likely a LINQ expert will read and answer it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are almost there..
Try this one:

```
       var prodsalesbygender = context.Orders
                                      .GroupBy(o => new
                                      {
                                          Gender = o.Person.Gender
                                      })
                                      .Select(g => new
                                      {
                                          Gender = g.Key,
                                          Products = g.Select(o => o.OrderProducts
                                                                    .GroupBy(op => op.Product)
                                                                    .Select(op => new
                                                                    {
                                                                        ProductName = op.Key.Name,
                                                                        Qty = op.Sum(op2 => op2.Qty),
                                                                        Price = op.Select(x => x.Product.Price)
                                                                                  .First(),
                                                                    })
                                                                    .Select(x => new
                                                                    {
                                                                        ProducName = x.ProductName,
                                                                        Qty = x.Qty,
                                                                        Price = x.Price,
                                                                        TotalPrice = x.Qty * x.Price
                                                                    }))
                                      });
```

In short, you just need more projection. In my suggested solution, first you group by the gender. The next step is to project the gender and 'list of product' directly (yes, the difficult part to get around is the `OrderProducts`). Within the `Products` we group it by product name, then take the total quantity (`Qty`) and set the `Price` - assuming the price for the same product is constant. The next step is to set the `TotalPrice`, the `Qty * Price` thing.

Ps. I am fully aware that this query had many deficiencies. Perhaps LINQ expert can give a better help on this.

It will result in a class something like:

```
  {
    Gender Gender
    IEnumerable<{ ProductName, Qty, Price, TotalPrice }> Products
  }
```

Yes, so much for anonymous type..

Nevertheless, i am baffled by the down votes as the question contains the models in question and the attempt OP have provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I ran your query and while it is calculating the totals, it is doing so by record at the Order level but not aggregating to the Products level. Getting closer... I appreciate your comment on downvotes - as a relative newcomer struggling to learn and eventually contribute, they are a bit disheartening. I'll learn in time.

Comment: Hi @deldridg, i understand your concern, however, `OrderProducts` only have `Qty` and no price of it.. hence we will need to fetch the prices from the `Product` themselves.

Comment: Hi @Bagus Tesa - that's the problem I'm trying to solve. As you correctly say, I'm trying to return the class you describe. Our new query is returning an IEnumerable<{ ProductName, Qty, Price, TotalPrice }> for each Order (100 in total) rather than a single list of products (10 in total), if that makes sense!

Comment: ah i see your problem, we should not strike the problem from `Orders` then.. since we are aggregating the `Products` based on gender and total sales, right? **edit** hmm, i think, from products is not feasible either.

Comment: Hmmm - sounds correct. I've been attacking the problem without the gender clause and appear to have gotten a little closer. Not sure if I can post 'partial solutions' here...

Comment: why not, you could post a partial solution here, perhaps someone can begin to improve that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally here is my solution, producing a result exactly as required.

```
var prodsalesbygender = context.OrderProducts
    .GroupBy(op => new
    {
        Gender = op.Order.Person.Gender
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Gender = g.Key.Gender,
        Products = g.GroupBy(op => op.Product)
        .Select(a => new
        {
            ProductName = a.Key.Name,
            Total = a.Sum(op => op.Qty * op.Product.Price)
        })
        .OrderBy(a => a.ProductName)
    });

foreach (var x in prodsalesbygender)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Gender);
    foreach (var a in x.Products)
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{a.ProductName} - {a.Total}");
}
```

My thanks to @Bagus Tesa